# MAX running total

Tags: google-sheets, max

I want to get `MAX` running total. Not just `MAX` from the column, but max running total updated on each new entry row. And so that it will not overwrite previous entry.

So far I came up with this:

`=ArrayFormula(if($C$3:$C="","",MAX("<="&row($C$3:$C),$C$3:$C,A2)))`

but it overwrites all the entries above. Giving me just total.

[image: Sample]

Here's [sample doc](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z6kFAn48EZoCQ-YzhvTcoeiI4kTjIShcgF_gPn2nA_g/edit?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 {QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE({
 QUERY(       Q2:Q,         "limit "&COUNTA(Q2:Q)), 
 QUERY(OFFSET(Q2:Q, -1, 0), "limit "&COUNTA(Q2:Q)-1)}),
 "select "&REGEXREPLACE(JOIN(, IF(LEN(Q2:Q),
 "max(Col"&ROW(Q2:Q)-ROW(Q2)+1&"),", )), ".\z", "")&"")),
 "select Col2"),
 "limit "&COUNTA(Q2:Q)),
 {""; QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE({
 QUERY(       Q2:Q,         "limit "&COUNTA(Q2:Q)),
 QUERY(OFFSET(Q2:Q, -1, 0), "limit "&COUNTA(Q2:Q)-1)}),
 "select "&REGEXREPLACE(JOIN(, IF(LEN(Q2:Q), 
 "max(Col"&ROW(Q2:Q)-ROW(Q2)+1&"),", )), ".\z", "")&"")),
 "select Col2 
  limit "&COUNTA(Q2:Q)-1)}}),
 "select "&REGEXREPLACE(JOIN(, IF(LEN(Q2:Q),
 "max(Col"&ROW(Q2:Q)-ROW(Q2)+1&"),", )), ".\z", "")&"")),
 "select Col2"))
```

[image]

Comment: That does exactly what I wanted. A little long and complicated for me, but works. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You might try, in A2 and copied down to suit:

```
=max(A1,C$1:C2)
```